# Cups - HP 8600 Pro - Print over Internet

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I setup Cups 1.5.3 and I found the same Printer 4 times.

- dnssd://Officejet%20Pro%208600%20%5BDC57A1%5D._printer._tcp.local/
- dnssd://Officejet%20Pro%208600%20%5BDC57A1%5D._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
- dnssd://Officejet%20Pro%208600%20%5BDC57A1%5D._ipp._tcp.local/
- socket://192.168.0.13:9100

I forwarded the Ports 631, 515, 161, 9100 on my Router to my Ubuntu Server 12.04 to CUPS

The Server has the IP 192.168.0.17
The Printer has the IP 192.168.0.13

The Printer will not be found over External IP or a Domain Name.

I dont know what else I should test to get connected to my Printer. Would be happy for any help, advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing hplip from the software center. This is the recommended method for your printer.

Source: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-OfficeJet_Pro_K8600